# How to draw white rectangle over black background in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I set up in Illustrator > File > Document Setup .. black color as shown [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mcLrpl4LTNI)

[image]

I try to create white / colorful (but not back to be able to see) rectangles over the black background.

So I've set some colors.

[image]

But I can not see rectangles on the canvas.

[image]

How able to see rectangle over black background?

## UPDATE

Here are the layer(s)

[image]

Comment: Ehm, shouldn't you just rearrange the layers?

Comment: How to rearrange layers? I can see only one sublayer as seen above. If I deselect rectangle, green color will dismiss. (stroke is set to 5px)

Comment: @Rvervuurt the Question is not using layers.

Comment: Hmm okay, never worked with a setup like that. Sorry :( What about making a new layer (the icon next to the trash can) and putting your shapes in that layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short you can't, not with simulate paper color. If you make the paper black then nothing appears because you've already used maximum ink. There are special inks available for this but its not something Illustrator simulates very well.

See this question for a little more information: [Printing in black paper?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36825/printing-in-black-paper)

What you probably want to do is set the default back so you have a white background instead of simulating black paper. Then create a black box the size of your art area and create new objects on top of it (which are the layers Rvervuurt was referring to).

Comment: Adding to this answer you can also after you've added the black rectangle in a layer then **lock that layer** and add any additional elements in different layers so that the black background doesn't become a *workaround hindrance*.